# Rails 3.1.0 and Resque -- "Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, resque, mysql2

Help! I keep getting "MySQL server has gone away" errors at what seems like random times. The same worker will run sometimes and then crash this way the next. I can't seem to find a pattern to the madness.

I have tried the following solutions:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.verify_active_connections!
```

in my perform methods in each task, as per the [resque faq](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/wiki/FAQ).

I have also tried this code:

```
adapter = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]['adapter']

if adapter == "mysql2"
 module ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters
   class Mysql2Adapter
     alias_method :execute_without_retry, :execute

     def execute(*args)
       execute_without_retry(*args)
     rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
       if e.message =~ /server has gone away/i
         warn "Server timed out, retrying"
         reconnect!
         retry
       else
         raise e
       end
     end
   end
 end
end
```

in an initializer, as [per code by a Resque developer](https://gist.github.com/238999), with some modifications found on StackOverflow and elsewhere.

I have also tried both of the above together. The results are the same.

I also tried setting `wait_timeout: 2147483` in my database.yml as per [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610426/rails-3-1-mysql2-error-mysql-server-has-gone-away) to no avail.

I am using:

- rails 3.1.0
- resque 1.20.0
- resque-scheduler 1.9.9
- mysql2 0.3.11

Everything is running on a Mac with RVM/Homebrew/Passenger. The mysql database is local to my machine.

Here is an example of an error:

```
Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away: SHOW FIELDS FROM `m_variables`
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:283:in `query'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:283:in `block in execute'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:244:in `block in log'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:239:in `log'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:283:in `execute'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:473:in `columns'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `with_connection'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:92:in `block in initialize'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:106:in `yield'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:106:in `default'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:106:in `block in initialize'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:711:in `yield'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:711:in `default'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:711:in `columns_hash'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:145:in `locking_enabled?'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:110:in `to_a'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:155:in `all'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:441:in `all'
/Users/fdot/Sites/mq/app/workers/m_variable_type_assigner.rb:25:in `perform'
```

and here is another example:

```
Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:687:in `query'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:687:in `block in exec_query'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:244:in `block in log'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:239:in `log'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:685:in `exec_query'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:679:in `select'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:470:in `find_by_sql'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:111:in `to_a'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:155:in `all'
/Users/fdot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:441:in `all'
/Users/fdot/Sites/mq/app/workers/transient_user_cleaner.rb:21:in `perform'
```

I'm at a loss here. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there are too many connections, which mysql fails to handle.

Try to limit the number of connections and processings you are doing. Rather than running parallel, make some request go serially.

This is more of a Mysql Error, rather than your language or framework error: see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) for more details

Comment: No, this is a common problem with Resque and mysql.  Resque doesn't reconnect ...