# Bind parameters in Rails mySQL empty

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using Rails 3.1.1, I'm getting occasional errors in production where it seems like the bind parameters on a mysql query are not there for some reason.  The error looks like this:

```
A ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid occurred in events#show:

Mysql::Error: : SELECT  `events`.* FROM `events`  WHERE `events`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:890:in `execute
```

It's not consistent on any insert or select, so I'm having trouble tracking it down.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Edit: updated with simpler example.

```
#events_controller.rb
def show
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])

  ...
end

#called with parameters: {"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"events", "id"=>"26"}
```

Comment: Can you please post the migration used to generate your `view_ips` table, your `app/models/view_ip.rb` file contents, and your `videos#viewed` action? Those will allow us to help you out.

Comment: You might try adding validations to the model object to trap the problem before it gets to the database. My guess would be that this is not actually a MySQL-related issue.

Comment: This is code for creating a `ViewIp`, in how many places do you do that? Show us the code. Add logging to the code, so you know which actual method/entry causes the nil values. Then check where and how those could become nil. Good luck.

Comment: Try upgrading Rails to 3.1.4 to see if this was just a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have gone away after upgrading to the latest rails - uncertain as to what it was.

Answer (score 0):

[The probable reason](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/StatementInvalid.html)

Check your database driver installation [here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/database/index.htm#_Database_Driver_Installation).

Comment: Doesn't installing the mysql gem build the driver from source anyway?

Comment: Not sure if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610426/rails-3-1-mysql2-error-mysql-server-has-gone-away can help you.